# How do I change the value of module.sig_enforce the Fedora kernel uses?

Tags: fedora, kernel-modules

I am running a Fedora kernel ver: 4.15.3-300.fc27.i686). I am trying to load a custom device driver. When I try to use the device (via an open() call in a C program) the call errors out with errno equal to 6 (ENODEV). When I look into this further, I see the following messages from dmesg:

```
[Tue Apr 24 17:34:32 2018] mymodule: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[Tue Apr 24 17:34:32 2018] mymodule: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

I think this is an issue with the driver not being signed. The [Fedora System Administrator's Guide](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/f27/system-administrators-guide/kernel-module-driver-configuration/Working_with_Kernel_Modules.html#sect-kernel-module-authentication-requirements) tells me that I need to rebuild the kernel to add a new key, but is also says that

> If UEFI Secure Boot is disabled and if the *module.sig_enforce* kernel
>   parameter has not been specified, then unsigned kernel modules and
>   signed kernel modules without a public key can be successfully loaded.

The computer I am running uses BIOS and does not support UEFI.

How do I find out what the current value of the *module.sig_enforce* setting is, and how do I change it?

Comment: Check your kernel command line. Usually in your grub configuration. If you didn't specify it when you booted the system, then it's not set.

Comment: What would the syntax for that look like? This is the line from grub.cfg: linux16 /vmlinuz-4.17.0-0.rc2.git0.1.vanilla.knurd.1.fc27.i686 root=/dev
/mapper/fedora-root ro rd.md.uuid=e8f1fe90:c8761aac:48d12b1a:7f3251b5 rd.lvm.lv=
fedora/root rd.md.uuid=7e8e6e41:46f1b47f:1b65099f:a33152a8 rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap
 rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
        initrd16 /initramfs-4.17.0-0.rc2.git0.1.vanilla.knurd.1.fc27.i686.img

Comment: I don't see `module.sig_enforce` anywhere in there. So you aren't using it.

Comment: Ahh - also found this in /usr/lib/modules/4.15.3-300.fc27.i686/config: #CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE is not set; however CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=y so I need to turn that off as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually [Elmer's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/637463/245871) is not incorrect.  The link referenced (snippet below) in the comment actually lists `/etc/grub2.cfg`.  Although it is a symbolic link, is still correct.  The practice of modifying this symbolic link (`/etc/grub2.cfg`) to `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` is risky and there are better/safer ways to accomplish the intended result.

Directly from: [Chapter 26. Working with GRUB 2 Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 | Red Hat Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-working_with_the_grub_2_boot_loader)

> 26.4. Making Persistent Changes to a GRUB 2 Menu Using the grubby Tool The grubby tool can be used to read information from, and make
> persistent changes to, the grub.cfg file. It enables, for example,
> changing GRUB 2 menu entries to specify what arguments to pass to a
> kernel on system start and changing the default kernel.

In Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, if grubby is invoked manually without specifying a GRUB 2 configuration file, it defaults to searching for `/etc/grub2.cfg`, which is a symbolic link to the `grub.cfg` file, whose location is architecture dependent. If that file cannot be found it will search for an architecture dependent default.

Answer (score -1):

In RHEL7 you can modify /etc/grub2.cfg and either remove it or set the value from yes to no. Since you are using Fedora it *should* be similar.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange, and thanks for your contribution! Unfortunately your answer is incorrect. There is no `/etc/grub2.cfg` in RHEL7, and we are discouraged to directly modify the Grub configuration file. The correct procedure is [documented at the Red Hat web site](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-working_with_the_grub_2_boot_loader).